# Blender Materials When Using .blend file in Unity

Tags: materials, unity

not sure if this should be here or in the Unity section of SE but here is my problem.

When importing an .blend file into Unity my material is the default grey one. When I look at what has been saved from Blender there is a material folder but they are all the grey one. I have only once been able to save a material correctly and I'm not sure how I did it, so I believe there is a way to save a .blend and export the material information as well?

Thanks in advanced for the help :)

edit: Just to add, the materials are saved in a folder called Materials in the same directory as the .blend files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else comes across this and needs an answer, I found that Unity and Blenders materials are not the same, when importing a material from Blender into Unity, Unity will try to create a material as best it can from the Blender one but it is never exactly the same, so it seems it is best to just re create them in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm finding this to be the case as well. Simple flat colored diffuse materials come into Unity with the proper names, and are attached to the proper triangles, but the diffuse color is reset to grey. If I name the colors properly, I can target them in Unity and reset the Albedo diffuse color to what I wanted and everything looks right. So close, and yet so far! Feels like there must be some way to get the color to sync up as well, but I guess UV mapping is the go-to methodology and perhaps this isn't so important?